# Cassandra query takes an excessive amount of time

Tags: cassandra

i am using cassandra to query a very large keyspace of entities (about 1 billion records), and the query seems to take a lot of time

the keyspace looks like:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS DB WITH REPLICATION = {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor':1};

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DB.table (time timeuuid, channelId int, datetime Timestamp, description text,
                    att1  boolean, 
                    att2  boolean,
                    att3 boolean,
                    att4  boolean,
                    image blob,
                    PRIMARY KEY(channelId, time));

ALTER TABLE  DB.table WITH compaction = {'class': 'DateTieredCompactionStrategy', 'base_time_seconds':'3600', 'max_sstable_age_days':'365'} 

ALTER TABLE  DB.table WITH GC_GRACE_SECONDS = 3600;

CREATE CUSTOM INDEX att1index ON SUSEDB.suspectentity (att1) USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex';

CREATE CUSTOM INDEX att2index ON SUSEDB.suspectentity (att2)  USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex';
```

running the following query

```
select channelid from suspectentity where channelid = 100 and time >= mintimeuuid('2016-06-29 23:00') and time <= mintimeuuid('2016-06-29 23:50') and att1= true;
```

the query runs for about 4.5 seconds, what is happening during "Merged data from memtables and 23 sstables" and why does it take so long?

```
>Preparing statement - 396
>
>Index mean cardinalities are attributesfacehat:-9223372036854775808. Scanning >with att1index. - 1545
>
>Computing ranges to query - 1583
>
>Submitting range requests on 1 ranges with a concurrency of 1 (-3.24259165E16 >rows per range expected) - 1638
>
>Submitted 1 concurrent range requests - 1688
>
>Executing read on susedb.suspectentity using index attributesfacehat - 5453
>
>Executing single-partition query on suspectentity  - 6450
>
>Acquiring sstable references - 6487
>
>cache hit for sstable 5520 - 6669
>
>cache hit for sstable 5487 - 6967

>cache hit for sstable 5569 - 36011
>
>cache hit for sstable 5309 - 36324
>
>cache hit for sstable 5085 - 36564
>
>Skipped 21/26 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 18 due to tombstones - 230753
>
>cache hit for sstable 5968 - 230920
>
>cache hit for sstable 5939 - 231177
>
>cache hit for sstable 5933 - 231363
>
>cache hit for sstable 5922 - 231533
>
>cache hit for sstable 5901 - 231717
>
>cache hit for sstable 5896 - 231892
>
>cache hit for sstable 5886 - 232056
>
>cache hit for sstable 5879 - 232265
>
>cache hit for sstable 5943 - 232418
>
>cache hit for sstable 5751 - 232615
>
>cache hit for sstable 5777 - 232769
>
>cache hit for sstable 5969 - 232949
>
>cache hit for sstable 5627 - 233133
>
>cache hit for sstable 5680 - 233321
>
>cache hit for sstable 5489 - 262047
>
>cache hit for sstable 5326 - 283459
>
>cache hit for sstable 5581 - 283539
>
>cache hit for sstable 5348 - 283620
>
>Merged data from memtables and 23 sstables - 4321883

>Read 500 live and 0 tombstone cells - 4324074
```

Comment: How many time entries are under each `channelId`?  As you are restricting by a partition key, this should be a fast query.  But if your partitions are exceptionally large you may need to re-partition or "bucket" to reduce partition size.

Comment: @Aaron -- I bet the answer is to use an `IN` query

Comment: there are about 20 million entries under each channelId

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the query is using range and indexes for generating a result. Both of these operations heavily utilize bloom filters to optimize their read paths. However due to the way this table was created, I bet the bloom filter chance is set too low because of the following:

Since the table was created without specifying a compaction strategy, the default of SizeTieredCompactionStrategy would be used, along with it's default of bloom_filter_fp_chance of 0.01 This is too low of a setting for DateTieredCompactionStrategy, the default for this compaction strategy is a bloom_filter_fp_chance of 0.1 (anything more is usually diminishing returns).

To adjust your bloom filter to the appropriate setting:

- `ALTER TABLE DB.table WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.1;`
- To apply the bloom filter change you will have to do one of the following:

  - Force Compactions on all of your cluster nodes for this table.
  - Upgrade SSTables on all of your cluster nodes for this table.
- Drop and recreate the table with the Compaction Strategy defined at the time of creation. Then reload your data. (Obviously not feasible if you don't have the means to repopulate your data).

Lastly it would be considered best practice to define your desired compaction strategy at the time of table creation, instead of an ALTER statement, to avoid issues like this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

What is the token assignment here. If this is a vnode token type, then chunk of each partition key will be distributed across your nodes.
Which might cause read latency. 
I dont see the partitions as wide rows from your data model.

But the compaction strategy which you are using is DateTieredCompactionStrategy. With Datetiered you should query on latest data. It is more useful for timeseries use cases. If the data is old which you want to query on, most of it will be flushed to disk and eventually be marked for tombstone. 
You can read more about this here : http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/dtcs-notes-from-the-field

Answer (score 0):

The 20M rows in your partition are the real issue here - your query generates a lot of java objects as it performs the read (see Cassandra jira #9754), which is probably filling up your new gen and causing pauses during promotion / collection.

Your data model is the proble, but you could work around it by raising your heap size (especially your new gen heap size if you're using CMS).